# Is there a source which would provide today's market close data like open high low close for a given stock list?

Tags: market-data

I am looking for a way to download a table of the bid, ask, open, high, low, close, change, 52-wk high, 52-wk low and P/E at market close for a given list of stocks in either .xls or .csv format.